# How to use a rotate animation while dragging view so center position keeps changing? To solve fromDegree toDegree issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

In my recyclerview, I want all items to jiggle/wobble/wiggle when a user holds an item and moves it. The problem I'm facing is that when a user holds the item and moves it in the same viewtype the wiggle is okay but when someone drags it to the top of the recyclerview (which is a header created as a viewtype in the recyclerview) the wiggle increases a lot.

On playing around with the values I realised that this was because even though the rotation angle the same, the farther it moved away from the item's center the rotation used to increase.

I tried doing this with an object animator also but it didn't help as that too had the same issue of the rotation angle.

Here is my wiggle code

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromDegrees="-5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="5" />
```

Here is a video of how it looks -
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16XKeIxTd2GYlfHCcM_BEDd100by9r-E7)

On bindView logic to start animating

```
((VHItem) holder).rlContainer.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view)
                    {
                        if (buPostModelList != null)
                        {
                            startAnimationItem = true;
                            isDragCover = true;
                            isEditCoverImage = false;
                            for (int i = 0; i <= buPostModelList.size(); i++)
                            {
                                if (recyclerView.getChildAt(i) != null && recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(recyclerView.getChildAt(i)).getItemViewType() != TYPE_HEADER)
                                {
                                    recyclerView.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.jiggle));
                                }
                            }
                            touchHelper.startDrag(holder);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

**EDIT**
A Sample project - [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pf_jDEMMG2fv_9qIMwyhRbgZ64KmsFlt/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please add the code where you apply this animation?

Comment: @DanielBeleza I apply it on the long click listener and then a boolean is set for all other cells which then animates on the bind view and all visible cells

Comment: Sorry, but thats not clear enough. It would really helped if you could simply edit your post and add more code of when you apply your animation.

Comment: From the video I think that your problem as to do with your pivots values, but since I'm not sure of how your are implementing your animation programmatically... I reach this conclusion because, like you said "the further it moved away from the item's center".

Comment: @DanielBeleza I've added the bindView code on where animation starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you move the view, the center of the rotation remains at the starting location but the view still moves five degrees back and forth, so it is like moving from the center of a merry-go-round to the periphery where the five degree movement covers a greater distance in the same amount of time.

I suggest that you move to an [*ObjectAnimator*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator) which does not have this problem.

> **ObjectAnimator**
>   
> This subclass of ValueAnimator provides support for animating properties on target objects. The constructors of this class take parameters to define the target object that will be animated as well as the name of the property that will be animated. Appropriate set/get functions are then determined internally and the animation will call these functions as necessary to animate the property.

**jiggle.xml**

This is a new *ObjectAnimator* xml for the jiggle effect. It is very similar to your *jiggle.xml*.

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueFrom="-5"
    android:valueTo="5"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

**VHItem**
Updated view holder with animator support.

```
class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView ivCollectionImage, ivRemoveIcon;
    private RelativeLayout rlContainer;
    private Animator mAnimator;

    public VHItem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivCollectionImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCollectionImage);
        ivRemoveIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivRemoveIcon);
        rlContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlContainer);
    }

    // Start animation. Inflate the animator lazily.
    public void startAnimator() {
        if (mAnimator == null) {
            mAnimator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.jiggle);
        }
        mAnimator.setTarget(itemView);
        mAnimator.start();
    }

    // Stop the animation. Set the rotation back to zero.
    public void stopAnimator() {
        if (mAnimator != null) {
            itemView.setRotation(0);
            mAnimator.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to update the rest of the adapter to work with the new animation.